# When to use stored procedures and SQL queries in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

What are the appropriate uses of stored procedures and SQL queries in EF code-first, particularly in ASP.NET web development? I was heavily dependent on them before I stared to use Entity Framework. However, with Entity Framework, hopefully we do not need to worry about writing SQL and creating stored procedures to create, insert, update, and read data, etc.

I know that using SQL might be good in some cases in EF, such as when clearing a whole table:

```
dbcontext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete from MyTable");
```

I do not want to underestimate the usability of stored procedures and SQL queries, and would like to learn the scenarios when they might be useful in EF code-first applications. Can you share good practices from your own projects?

Comment: This is an opinion question which is off topic for SO and so will likely be closed.  My opinion is that you have an ORM exactly for the abstraction to not have to use SQL, so dont.

Comment: @paqogomez where should I post it?

Comment: I like to use stored procedures where I need a view of several tables in a single query, for instance with several joins.  But for a single table, where I want to be able to update/insert/delete I will use LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea.  You make some assertions that I dont know are valid.  (like the delete example.)  And even with that example you are using the framework to execute the sql, so I dont see the point of trying to ask about some special way to use sql.  Thats how EF uses sql.

Comment: @PaulGibson wouldnt that be a view?

Comment: @paqogomez I suppose you could use a view for that, but I have used sps for that case just as effectively.

Comment: IMO SPs are completely un-necessary. Performance-wise you don't gain much (if any) in comparison to a reasonable SQL statement, and it means you have database code in two places which makes maintenance harder. the only place you might *need* a SP is if you are using a cursor or similar, in which case you probably want to re-think things anyway.

Comment: How does implementing an SP make database code appear in two places? Business Logic in the DB vs business logcic in the app.... it's an argument no one ever wins.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid its not 'business logic' in the database its just a query. And you still need to write a query to execute your SP in your app, that's more code and more obscure code than having it all in your app.

Comment: Stored procedures are far more than queries. They are procedural code. They don't even have to return data like a query. The SQL command that you write in your app is just executing sp name with parameters, just like a calling a function. This has been argued many times already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my **opinion**, I think there are plenty of times where you may need to do something significantly complex, where it warrants keeping that complexity in a stored proc.

Some examples might include;

- `BULK INSERT` operations from a user uploaded file to process
- Recursive CTEs
- Use of Temp Tables/Table Variables to perform advanced processing
- Making use of existing database functions, procs, linked servers etc
- Instances where the queries are sufficiently advanced that the query plan generated with an ORM is less than optimal, and you know you can do better with plain SQL. Also being able to use query hints in SQL is quite beneficial (albeit a rarity too)

I've been involved in projects in the past where we let the ORM handle the vast majority of instances, but we had a handful of places where we deferred to hand crafted SQL where it was deemed more appropriate.

I wouldn't suggest that any ORM is suitable for **all** tasks.

To a degree, I'd also suggest that the ability of your DEV team might also help you decide what to use where. Your ORM might be fine for simple CRUD and semi-advanced search type queries. However, for more complicated processing, if your team are going to spend twice as long trying to do something in an ORM than simply doing it in SQL, then you have to ask if that is a good use of time and money.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I guess as an independent programmer developing small-scaled projects, I am unlikely to be in need of SPs and SQL when using Entity Framework.

Comment: That is possibly true, but if you are working with data and databases a lot, then I'd highly recommend getting your hands dirty with SQL (even just via a management tool like SSMS), so you can make informed decisions as to when one might be more useful over another.

Comment: I actually got involved in SQL a lot since I used to create dozens of SPs in the MS SQL Server Manager and use them in my asp.net c# application :)

Answer (score 4):

Very rarely(<0.1%) you would have a case to use stored procs, in rest of 99.9% you should use ORM or entity framework in your case.

Here are the few instances I have used stored procs.

i) **Full Text Search** like Google with complex requirements like proximity search, word breaker, stemmers , INFLECTIONAL etc.

ii) Incase of some table columns are **encrypted** and you have queries with these columns in conditional statements.

iii) For Database to database migrations, sql jobs etc.

may be in few other cases I cannot remember now.

Comment: thanks for the examples pjobs!